# Rollback + Commit some changes

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a case where I need to Rollback changes on the Database, but also, I want to keep the inserted Logs.

Illustration:

> ```
> Add processing log
>  Insert some data
>  Insert some data
>  Insert some data
> Add processing log
>  Do some checking...
>   Checking Failed
>   Add processing log
>   Rollback;
> ```

- Log table on the same database of the other inserted data

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is, I would normally expect a centralized logging routine and in that logging package, in the function you use to write the log, insert this line after the procedure header declaration

```
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
```

That will place the log insertions on a different transaction to the calling routine, allowing you to commit the log regardless of what happens in the parent routine.

Docs Details : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/autotransaction_pragma.htm